# Compilation error due to method argument mismatch

Tags: java

At the time of compilation, it is not accepting the way I have defined my methods. It is a code to find the determinant and transpose of a matrix. I need help regarding the method calling in my code.

```
import java.util.*;

class CodeMet5 {    
    //public int transpose(double a[n][n])

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner c=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the matrix order : ");
        int n = c.nextInt();
        double a[][]=new double[n][n];
        System.out.println("Enter the matrix elements one by one as a11,a12,a13,..a21,a22,..");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
                a[i][j]=c.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The matrix is : \n");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
                System.out.print(a[i][j]+"  ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

        double determinant=det(a[n][n]);
        System.out.println("The transpose of this matrix is: \n");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++) {    
                double t=a[i][j];
                a[i][j]=a[j][i];
                a[j][i]=t;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
                System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        System.out.println("determinant = "+determinant);
    }

    public static double formDetMat(double A[p][p],int l,int m) {
        int n=p-1;
        int r=l+1;
        int s=0;
        double a[][]=new double[n][n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
                if(s!=m) {
                    a[i][j]=A[r][s];
                    s++;
                } else {
                    a[i][j]=A[r][s+1];
                    s+=2;
                }
            }
            r++;
        }
        return a[][];
    }

    public static double det(double b[p][p]) {
        if(p>2) {
            double deter=0;
            for(j=0;j<p;j++) {
                double tired=formDetMat(b[p][p],0,j));
                deter+=Math.pow(-1,2+j)*b[0][j]*det(tired);
            }
        } else if(p==2) {
            double deter=b[0][0]*b[1][1]-b[0][1]*b[1][0];
        }
        return deter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Java has methods, not functions. Which method call is it exactly that doesn't work? Where do you call it?

Comment: `public static double formDetMat(double A[p][p]`  See anything wrong there?

Comment: You code has some serious syntax issues. You should start with learning the syntax of Java.

Comment: both methods are showing errors.

Comment: you dont heed square brackets to pass array just do `det(a)` and also remove `p` from `double A[p][p]` on receiving function

Comment: double b[p][p] what's that supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

You should pass the entire matrix to your methods, not a single cell of the matrix (especially not a cell that doesn't exist).

For example :

change

```
double determinant=det(a[n][n])
```

to

```
double determinant=det(a);
```

And you also have an error in the methods' signature.

It should be :

```
public static double det(double b[][])
```

or

```
public static double det(double[][] b)
```

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky That's another error. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Then how do I check the order of the matrix if I am not passing p value ?

Comment: @KaramvirKaurBTechMetallurg `b.length` is the number of rows and `b[0].length` the number of columns (assuming all rows have equal length).

Comment: Moreover, how do we return an array from a method ? What datatype has to be used ? Because, the error the compiler is throwing is :actual argument double cannot be converted to double[][] by method invocation conversion

Comment: @KaramvirKaurBTechMetallurg If you want to return a matrix, the return type should be `double[][]`.